# #1064 MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentanto importar un archivo tipo .sql en HeidiSQL. Cuando intento ejecutar el archivo para rellenar una tablas ya creadas me disapara el siguiente error:

> Error de SQL(1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to you MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'insert into...

He detectado que había un espacio en blanco en la primera línea del código. Tras quitarlo, el código se ha empezado a ejecutar pero se ha mostrado otro error. El error es el siguiente:

> Error de SQL (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails ('pac4'.
>   'nonevaluableactivity',CONSTRAINT'nonevaluableactivity_ibfk_1'FOREIGN
>   KEY('subject_id') REFERENCES 'subject'(subject_id')).

Tras leer algunos comentarios, se había propuesto introducir al inicio y al final las siguientes sentencias respectivamente:

```
SET foreign_key_checks= 0 
SET foreign_key_checks= 1
```

Tras introducirlas y volver a ejecutar el código, se muestra el siguiente error:

> Error de SQL (1062): Duplicate entry 'M1.448-0' for key 'PRIMARY'.

A continuación se muestra el código de las tablas de la base de datos y el código a ejecutar para rellenarlas:

**Código de las tablas**

```
CREATE TABLE `assessableactivity` (
    `subject_id` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `act_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `description` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `statement` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `statement_publication` DATE NOT NULL,
    `delivery_deadline` DATE NOT NULL,
    `solution_publication` DATE NOT NULL,
    `rating_publication` DATE NOT NULL,
    `value_pct` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`, `act_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `assessableactivity_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subject` (`subject_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `master` (
    `master_id` INT(20) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `curriculum_rev` DATE NOT NULL,
    `ects` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`master_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`name`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `nonevaluableactivity` (
    `subject_id` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `act_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `description` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `start_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `end_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`, `act_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `nonevaluableactivity_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subject` (`subject_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
;

CREATE TABLE `subject` (
    `subject_id` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `language` ENUM('Català','Castellano','English') NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `description` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    `ECTS` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `m_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`),
    INDEX `m_id` (`m_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `subject_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`m_id`) REFERENCES `master` (`master_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Código para importar contenido en las tablas**

```
SET foreign_key_checks=0;

insert into Master values (1,'MU Data Science','2017/6/6');
insert into Master values (2,'MU Elearning','2015/9/9');
insert into Master values (3,'MU Bussines Administration','2014/9/12');

insert into Subject values ('M2.965','Disseny de Bases de Dades','Català', 'Dissenyar bases de dades relacionals de qualitat, partint d''un conjunt de requisits del sistema d''informació i procurant que l''explotació de les dades es pugui dur a terme de forma correcta i eficient.', 6, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.865','Diseño de Bases de Datos','Castellano', 'Diseñar bases de datos relacionales de calidad, partiendo de un conjunto de requisitos del sistema de información y procurando que la explotación de los datos se pueda llevar a cabo de forma correcta y eficiente.', 6, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.765','DataBase Design','English', 'Design quality relational databases, based on a set of requirements of the information system and ensuring that the exploitation of data can be carried out correctly and efficiently.', 6, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.955','Big Data','Català', null, 6, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.855','Big Data','Castellano', null, 6, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.755','Big Data','English', null, 6, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.915','Mineria de dades','Català', 'Conjunt de mètodes procedents de la Intel·ligència Artificial, que formen el nucli essencial de la disciplina coneguda com Data Mining. Els conceptes estadístics són molt útils en aquesta assignatura i permetran avaluar millor algunes de les tècniques que s''estudiaran.', 6, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.815','Mineria de datos','Castellano', 'Conjunto de procedimientos de la Inteligencia Artificial, la forma esencial de la disciplina con la minería de datos. El concepto estadístico es útil en la asignatura y en las hojas de ruta de las empresas especializadas.', 6, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.715','Data Mining','English', 'A set of methods from Artificial Intelligence, which form the core of the discipline known as Data Mining. The statistical concepts are very useful in this subject and will allow to better evaluate some of the techniques that will be studied.', 6, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.905','TFM','Català', null, 12, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.805','TFM','Castellano', null, 12, 1);
insert into Subject values ('M2.705','MFW','English', null, 12, 1);

insert into Subject values ('M1.448','Disseny i gestió de projectes e-learning','Català', 'Dissenyar i gestionar projectes relacionats amb l''aprenentatge en línia.', 6, 2);
insert into Subject values ('M1.548','Diseño y gestión de proyectos e-learning','Castellano', 'Diseñar y gestionar proyectos relacionados con el aprendizaje en linea', 6, 2);
insert into Subject values ('M1.648','Fonaments de disseny tecnopedagògic','Català', null, 6, 2);
insert into Subject values ('M1.748','Fundamentos de diseño tecnopedagógico','Castellano', null, 6, 2);
insert into Subject values ('M1.948','TFM','Català', null, 12, 2);
insert into Subject values ('M1.848','TFM','Castellano', null, 12, 2);

insert into Subject values ('M3.145','MFW','English', null, 12, 3);
insert into Subject values ('M3.155','TFM','Castellano', null, 12, 3);

insert into AssessableActivity values ('M2.965',1,'Model relacional i instalació del programari', null, '','2018/10/10','2018/10/18','2018/10/20','2018/10/29',0.15);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M2.865',1,'Modelo relacional e instalación de software', null, '','2018/10/10','2018/10/18','2018/10/20','2018/10/29',0.15);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M2.965',2,'Disseny conceptual pas a pas', null, '','2018/10/31','2018/11/14','2018/11/14','2018/11/30',0.15);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M2.865',2,'Diseño conceptual paso a paso', null, '','2018/10/31','2018/11/14','2018/11/14','2018/11/30',0.15);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M2.965',3,'Disseny conceptual i lògic', null, '','2018/11/20','2018/12/5','2018/12/7','2018/12/18',0.35);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M2.865',3,'Diseño conceptual y lógico', null, '','2018/11/20','2018/12/5','2018/12/7','2018/12/18',0.35);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M2.965',4,'Creació i manipulació SQL', null, '','2018/12/12','2018/12/29','2018/12/31','2019/1/8',0.35);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M2.865',4,'Creación y manipulación SQL', null, '','2018/12/12','2018/12/29','2018/12/31','2019/1/8',0.35);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.448',1,'Introducció a la gestió i la organització en e-learning', null,'','2018/9/19','2018/10/15','2018/10/18','2018/10/30', 0.20);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.448',2,'Formació equips treball i proposta projecte', null,'','2018/10/16','2018/11/9','2018/11/12','2018/11/27', 0.20);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.448',3,'Presentació i defensa virtual del projecte', null,'','2018/11/10','2018/12/19','2018/12/21','2018/12/31', 0.40);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.448',4,'Portal del projecte i difusió a la xarxa', null,'','2018/12/26','2019/1/9','2019/1/12','2019/1/27', 0.20);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.648',1,'Debat sobre objectes d''aprenentatge', null,'','2018/9/19','2018/10/15','2018/10/18','2018/10/30', 0.05);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.648',2,'Activitat oberta de redacció col·laborativa en Wiki', null,'','2018/10/16','2018/11/9','2018/11/12','2018/11/27', 0.15);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.648',3,'Ús d''un SGA per a la creació d''una experiència educativa', null,'','2018/11/10','2018/12/19','2018/12/21','2018/12/31', 0.20);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.648',4,'Debat sobre Sistemes de Gestió de Continguts', null,'','2018/12/2','2019/12/19','2019/1/12','2019/1/27', 0.20);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.648',5,'Aplicació d''estàndards i formats tècnics I (IEEE LOM, SCORM)', null,'','2018/11/10','2018/12/19','2018/12/21','2018/12/31', 0.20);
insert into AssessableActivity values ('M1.648',6,'Aplicació d''estàndards i formats tècnics II (IMS LD)', null,'','2018/12/2','2019/12/19','2019/1/12','2019/1/27', 0.20);

insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.965','M1','Conceptes introductoris', null,'2018/9/19','2018/9/23');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.865','M1','Conceptos introductorios', null,'2018/9/19','2018/9/23');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.965','M2','Introducció', null,'2018/9/24','2018/9/30');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.865','M2','Introducción', null,'2018/9/24','2018/9/30');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.965','M3','Model relacional', null,'2018/10/1','2018/10/14');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.865','M3','Modelo relacional', null,'2018/10/1','2018/10/14');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.965','M4','Disseny conceptual', null,'2018/10/15','2018/11/4');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.865','M4','Diseño conceptual', null,'2018/10/15','2018/11/4');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.965','M5','Disseny lògic', null,'2018/11/5','2018/11/18');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.865','M5','Diseño lógico', null,'2018/11/5','2018/11/18');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.965','M6','SQL', null,'2018/12/3','2018/12/16');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M2.865','M6','SQL', null,'2018/12/3','2018/12/16');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M1.448','M1','Introducció a la gestió i la organització en e-learning', null,'2018/9/19','2018/10/15');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M1.448','M2','Formació equips treball i proposta projecte', null,'2018/10/16','2018/11/9');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M1.448','M3','Presentació i defensa virtual del projecte', null,'2018/11/10','2018/12/19');
insert into NonEvaluableActivity values ('M1.448','M4','Portal del projecte i difusió a la xarxa', null,'2018/12/26','2019/1/9');

SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: El campo de la fehca es de tipo date? en caso afirmativo le debes pasar la fehca en formato Y-m-d no d/m/Y

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir el código que has utilizado? pero no con una captura de pantalla, para así que nos sea más facíl observar donde puede estar el error.

Comment: te estan lloviendo los votos negativos por que en tu pregunta el código va como texto y no como imagen y además por que si tienes información que agregar va en la misma pregunta dando clic en editar y no en la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos primero que nada al momento de insertar tus sencentencias sql me ha presentado algunos errores como:

- tablas en minusculas
- longitud en campos demasiado cortos para el contenido a insertar

Las tablas que presentaban dicho error eran:

- subject -> Campo description se pasa de 200 a  300
- assessableactivity -> Campo name se pasa de 50 a 100
- nonevaluableactivity -> Campo name se pasa de 50 a  100

Otro error que genero fue que estas tratando de ingresar varchar a un campo integer:

- tabla NonEvaluableActivity -> Campo act_id

por este motivo se cambia de tipo int a varchar.

El codigo completo que genera desde PhpMyadmin es:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.15.10
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Servidor: localhost
-- Tiempo de generación: 27-12-2018 a las 14:29:32
-- Versión del servidor: 5.6.41
-- Versión de PHP: 5.4.16

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `stackoverflow`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `assessableactivity`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assessableactivity` (
  `subject_id` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `act_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `statement` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `statement_publication` date NOT NULL,
  `delivery_deadline` date NOT NULL,
  `solution_publication` date NOT NULL,
  `rating_publication` date NOT NULL,
  `value_pct` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `assessableactivity`
--

INSERT INTO `assessableactivity` (`subject_id`, `act_id`, `name`, `description`, `statement`, `statement_publication`, `delivery_deadline`, `solution_publication`, `rating_publication`, `value_pct`) VALUES
('M1.448', 1, 'Introducció a la gestió i la organització en e-learning', NULL, '', '2018-09-19', '2018-10-15', '2018-10-18', '2018-10-30', 0.2),
('M1.448', 2, 'Formació equips treball i proposta projecte', NULL, '', '2018-10-16', '2018-11-09', '2018-11-12', '2018-11-27', 0.2),
('M1.448', 3, 'Presentació i defensa virtual del projecte', NULL, '', '2018-11-10', '2018-12-19', '2018-12-21', '2018-12-31', 0.4),
('M1.448', 4, 'Portal del projecte i difusió a la xarxa', NULL, '', '2018-12-26', '2019-01-09', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-27', 0.2),
('M1.648', 1, 'Debat sobre objectes d''aprenentatge', NULL, '', '2018-09-19', '2018-10-15', '2018-10-18', '2018-10-30', 0.05),
('M1.648', 2, 'Activitat oberta de redacció col·laborativa en Wiki', NULL, '', '2018-10-16', '2018-11-09', '2018-11-12', '2018-11-27', 0.15),
('M1.648', 3, 'Ús d''un SGA per a la creació d''una experiència educativa', NULL, '', '2018-11-10', '2018-12-19', '2018-12-21', '2018-12-31', 0.2),
('M1.648', 4, 'Debat sobre Sistemes de Gestió de Continguts', NULL, '', '2018-12-02', '2019-12-19', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-27', 0.2),
('M1.648', 5, 'Aplicació d''estàndards i formats tècnics I (IEEE LOM, SCORM)', NULL, '', '2018-11-10', '2018-12-19', '2018-12-21', '2018-12-31', 0.2),
('M1.648', 6, 'Aplicació d''estàndards i formats tècnics II (IMS LD)', NULL, '', '2018-12-02', '2019-12-19', '2019-01-12', '2019-01-27', 0.2),
('M2.865', 1, 'Modelo relacional e instalación de software', NULL, '', '2018-10-10', '2018-10-18', '2018-10-20', '2018-10-29', 0.15),
('M2.865', 2, 'Diseño conceptual paso a paso', NULL, '', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-14', '2018-11-14', '2018-11-30', 0.15),
('M2.865', 3, 'Diseño conceptual y lógico', NULL, '', '2018-11-20', '2018-12-05', '2018-12-07', '2018-12-18', 0.35),
('M2.865', 4, 'Creación y manipulación SQL', NULL, '', '2018-12-12', '2018-12-29', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-08', 0.35),
('M2.965', 1, 'Model relacional i instalació del programari', NULL, '', '2018-10-10', '2018-10-18', '2018-10-20', '2018-10-29', 0.15),
('M2.965', 2, 'Disseny conceptual pas a pas', NULL, '', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-14', '2018-11-14', '2018-11-30', 0.15),
('M2.965', 3, 'Disseny conceptual i lògic', NULL, '', '2018-11-20', '2018-12-05', '2018-12-07', '2018-12-18', 0.35),
('M2.965', 4, 'Creació i manipulació SQL', NULL, '', '2018-12-12', '2018-12-29', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-08', 0.35);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `master`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `master` (
  `master_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `curriculum_rev` date NOT NULL,
  `ects` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `master`
--

INSERT INTO `master` (`master_id`, `name`, `curriculum_rev`, `ects`) VALUES
(1, 'MU Data Science', '2017-06-06', 0),
(2, 'MU Elearning', '2015-09-09', 0),
(3, 'MU Bussines Administration', '2014-09-12', 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `nonevaluableactivity`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `nonevaluableactivity` (
  `subject_id` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `act_id` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `nonevaluableactivity`
--

INSERT INTO `nonevaluableactivity` (`subject_id`, `act_id`, `name`, `description`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES
('M1.448', 'M1', 'Introducció a la gestió i la organització en e-learning', NULL, '2018-09-19', '2018-10-15'),
('M1.448', 'M2', 'Formació equips treball i proposta projecte', NULL, '2018-10-16', '2018-11-09'),
('M1.448', 'M3', 'Presentació i defensa virtual del projecte', NULL, '2018-11-10', '2018-12-19'),
('M1.448', 'M4', 'Portal del projecte i difusió a la xarxa', NULL, '2018-12-26', '2019-01-09'),
('M2.865', 'M1', 'Conceptos introductorios', NULL, '2018-09-19', '2018-09-23'),
('M2.865', 'M2', 'Introducción', NULL, '2018-09-24', '2018-09-30'),
('M2.865', 'M3', 'Modelo relacional', NULL, '2018-10-01', '2018-10-14'),
('M2.865', 'M4', 'Diseño conceptual', NULL, '2018-10-15', '2018-11-04'),
('M2.865', 'M5', 'Diseño lógico', NULL, '2018-11-05', '2018-11-18'),
('M2.865', 'M6', 'SQL', NULL, '2018-12-03', '2018-12-16'),
('M2.965', 'M1', 'Conceptes introductoris', NULL, '2018-09-19', '2018-09-23'),
('M2.965', 'M2', 'Introducció', NULL, '2018-09-24', '2018-09-30'),
('M2.965', 'M3', 'Model relacional', NULL, '2018-10-01', '2018-10-14'),
('M2.965', 'M4', 'Disseny conceptual', NULL, '2018-10-15', '2018-11-04'),
('M2.965', 'M5', 'Disseny lògic', NULL, '2018-11-05', '2018-11-18'),
('M2.965', 'M6', 'SQL', NULL, '2018-12-03', '2018-12-16');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `subject`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject` (
  `subject_id` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `language` enum('Català','Castellano','English') COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ECTS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `m_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `subject`
--

INSERT INTO `subject` (`subject_id`, `name`, `language`, `description`, `ECTS`, `m_id`) VALUES
('M1.448', 'Disseny i gestió de projectes e-learning', 'Català', 'Dissenyar i gestionar projectes relacionats amb l''aprenentatge en línia.', 6, 2),
('M1.548', 'Diseño y gestión de proyectos e-learning', 'Castellano', 'Diseñar y gestionar proyectos relacionados con el aprendizaje en linea', 6, 2),
('M1.648', 'Fonaments de disseny tecnopedagògic', 'Català', NULL, 6, 2),
('M1.748', 'Fundamentos de diseño tecnopedagógico', 'Castellano', NULL, 6, 2),
('M1.848', 'TFM', 'Castellano', NULL, 12, 2),
('M1.948', 'TFM', 'Català', NULL, 12, 2),
('M2.705', 'MFW', 'English', NULL, 12, 1),
('M2.715', 'Data Mining', 'English', 'A set of methods from Artificial Intelligence, which form the core of the discipline known as Data Mining. The statistical concepts are very useful in this subject and will allow to better evaluate some of the techniques that will be studied.', 6, 1),
('M2.755', 'Big Data', 'English', NULL, 6, 1),
('M2.765', 'DataBase Design', 'English', 'Design quality relational databases, based on a set of requirements of the information system and ensuring that the exploitation of data can be carried out correctly and efficiently.', 6, 1),
('M2.805', 'TFM', 'Castellano', NULL, 12, 1),
('M2.815', 'Mineria de datos', 'Castellano', 'Conjunto de procedimientos de la Inteligencia Artificial, la forma esencial de la disciplina con la minería de datos. El concepto estadístico es útil en la asignatura y en las hojas de ruta de las empresas especializadas.', 6, 1),
('M2.855', 'Big Data', 'Castellano', NULL, 6, 1),
('M2.865', 'Diseño de Bases de Datos', 'Castellano', 'Diseñar bases de datos relacionales de calidad, partiendo de un conjunto de requisitos del sistema de información y procurando que la explotación de los datos se pueda llevar a cabo de forma correcta y eficiente.', 6, 1),
('M2.905', 'TFM', 'Català', NULL, 12, 1),
('M2.915', 'Mineria de dades', 'Català', 'Conjunt de mètodes procedents de la Intel·ligència Artificial, que formen el nucli essencial de la disciplina coneguda com Data Mining. Els conceptes estadístics són molt útils en aquesta assignatura i permetran avaluar millor algunes de les tècniques que s''estudiaran.', 6, 1),
('M2.955', 'Big Data', 'Català', NULL, 6, 1),
('M2.965', 'Disseny de Bases de Dades', 'Català', 'Dissenyar bases de dades relacionals de qualitat, partint d''un conjunt de requisits del sistema d''informació i procurant que l''explotació de les dades es pugui dur a terme de forma correcta i eficient.', 6, 1),
('M3.145', 'MFW', 'English', NULL, 12, 3),
('M3.155', 'TFM', 'Castellano', NULL, 12, 3);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `assessableactivity`
--
ALTER TABLE `assessableactivity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`,`act_id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `master`
--
ALTER TABLE `master`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`master_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `nonevaluableactivity`
--
ALTER TABLE `nonevaluableactivity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`,`act_id`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `subject`
--
ALTER TABLE `subject`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`),
  ADD KEY `m_id` (`m_id`);

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `assessableactivity`
--
ALTER TABLE `assessableactivity`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `assessableactivity_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subject` (`subject_id`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `nonevaluableactivity`
--
ALTER TABLE `nonevaluableactivity`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `nonevaluableactivity_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subject` (`subject_id`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `subject`
--
ALTER TABLE `subject`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `subject_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`m_id`) REFERENCES `master` (`master_id`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Al momento de usar tus sentencias es muy importante el orden de como creas las tablas como Primero master que es la tabla principal, a continuacion subject  que hereda id de master.. y asi sucesivamente, lo mismo ocurre en las sentencias insert.

El error que te generaba :

> Error de SQL (1062): Duplicate entry 'M1.448-0' for key 'PRIMARY'.

Es debido a que ya inserto dicho registro y tratas de insertarlo nuevamente, lo mismo me ocurrio, por cierto otra cosa tambien es de que tus tablas estan en minusculas y las sentencias insert estan en mayusculas, debes verificar ello.

Tambien no he utilizado:

```
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.. y suerte..!!

Comment: Tiene buena pinta.. voy a ver qué pasa! Una pregunta de principiante... la tabla master debería contener una columna ects si se calcula a partir de la suma de los creditos de las asignaturas ects? (atributo derivado), porque al principio yo incluí este atributo y no me cargaba los datos, después lo quité y me los cargó.